# SQL ORDER BY IN SELECT FROM STRING SPLIT or Comma Separated Value

Tags: sql, linq

I would like to know if is it possible in SQL to order by the query from the `String_split` or csv like this

```
select item_number 
from table1 
order by ('335484,105666,105681,338706,144516') 
      offset 0 rows fetch next 30 rows only
```

This list is the `item_number` with `offset` and `fetch next`..

Thanks

Comment: What exactly you want ? Could you add expected result as well ?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

No it's no possible , each field you're trying to order by should be separate , in your case each will be within a single quotes then separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use string operations for this.  Because the question is tagged linq, let me assume you are using SQL Server:

```
select item_number 
from table1 
order by charindex(',', item_number + ',', ',' + '335484,105666,105681,338706,144516' + ',') 
offset 0 rows fetch next 30 rows only;
```

This returns the location of the number in the string and uses that location for ordering.

You can do something similar in other databases.